# i have dual booted my hp laptop by intsalling ubuntu 18.04. my wi-fi is not working it shows wifi adapter not found . Please help me to fix this

Tags: drivers, wireless

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

tried these commands but at end i got some steps for rebooting but i don't know how to do MOk or something it says

[image: message after last code i entered]

and then i rebooted but didn't know what to do so just started Ubuntu normally. my WiFi still does not work

Comment: First of all determine which Wifi adapter you have. Run `lshw -C network`.

Comment: @Kulfy.    realtek

Comment: Realtek has many wifi cards. Which specific card do you have? For eg. RTL8273BE

Comment: Somebody actually reads my posts on the forums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secure boot will block unauthorized kernel modules to load. To install the proprietary driver, you need to turn off the secure boot during the installation. This is what your screenshot is talking about. Regarding how to walk through the whole process, please follow the steps in this Ubuntu wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS (in your case, the term DKMS mentioned in the wiki page is equivalent to your wifi driver.)

In the meantime, you may need the command `ubuntu-drivers` to help you to select the driver you need automatically and install it for you, e.g. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.

Comment: Thanks alot the code series i tried actually worked i just have to disable my secure boot. But i wanna know that now i have to let my secure boot disabled always in order to use my wi-fi driver???